# Inserting Horizontal Line element between cells

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how can I place a `hr` element between the top cells of the table and bottom cells. So in photo provided. There would be a horizontal line between Future Skills, Star = One Year, and Shining-Star = Five Years. And the other cells including skills, years in stars, etc. Ideally in HTML but CSS is decent as well.

```html
<table cellspacing="36">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Future Skills</h3>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <h5>⭐ = One Year</h5>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <h5> = Five year</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Frontend Coding</td>
    <td>HTML, CSS, Javascript </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
    <td>Frontend Coding</td>
    <td>HTML, CSS, Javascript </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>UX Design</td>
    <td>Figma, Illustrator, and Photoshop</td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
    <td>UX Design</td>
    <td>Figma, Illustrator, and Photoshop</td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Backend Programming</td>
    <td>Python, C, and Java </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>

    <td>Backend Programming</td>
    <td>Python, C, and Java </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Live Server Screenshot of Current Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe6HM.jpg)

Comment: I don't see any horizontal rule in the picture provided. But you can place an `<hr>` inside a `<td>` easily enough. Maybe in a new row with a `colspan`?

Comment: How would that be done? what HTML would be added to mine. Please provide some code.

Comment: did you check the solution below? @Beaner21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hr` usually go well with no-column content like paragraph (`p`), so in the table structure, it's not a convenient way to set separators

A table always has borders naturally. Therefore, I'd suggest you set `border` for each `tr` (table row) in CSS to achieve it instead of `hr`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="36">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Future Skills</h3>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <h5>⭐ = One Year</h5>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <h5> = Five year</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Frontend Coding</td>
    <td>HTML, CSS, Javascript </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
    <td>Frontend Coding</td>
    <td>HTML, CSS, Javascript </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>UX Design</td>
    <td>Figma, Illustrator, and Photoshop</td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
    <td>UX Design</td>
    <td>Figma, Illustrator, and Photoshop</td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Backend Programming</td>
    <td>Python, C, and Java </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>

    <td>Backend Programming</td>
    <td>Python, C, and Java </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you still want to use `hr`, you can try this way

```html
<table cellspacing="36">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Future Skills</h3>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <h5>⭐ = One Year</h5>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <h5> = Five year</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Frontend Coding</td>
    <td>HTML, CSS, Javascript </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
    <td>Frontend Coding</td>
    <td>HTML, CSS, Javascript </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>UX Design</td>
    <td>Figma, Illustrator, and Photoshop</td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
    <td>UX Design</td>
    <td>Figma, Illustrator, and Photoshop</td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Backend Programming</td>
    <td>Python, C, and Java </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>

    <td>Backend Programming</td>
    <td>Python, C, and Java </td>
    <td>
      <h5></h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```